# Dynamically calling stored procedures using Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an API controller endpoint that allows a caller to dynamically execute stored procedures.  The controller method takes a request model that contains the stored proc name and a dictionary of parameters for the procedure.  The request model looks something like this

```
public class GenericSprocRequest
{
    public string SprocName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

In regards to the Parameters dictionary, the key is the parameter name and the value is the parameter value.

Here is an example of a request:

```
{
  "SprocName":"dbo.UpdateCustomer",
  "Parameters":
  {
     "CustName": "John Doe",
     "CustPhone": "404-555-1212"
  }
}
```

My question is, using EF Core 7, how do I build the list of parameters based on the dictionary then call the stored procedure passing that list of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not getting into question why (because it seems like something you should not do). Assuming you have only string parameters you can try something like the following (example for PostgreSQL):

```cs
await ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(..., dict.Select(kvp =>
    new NpgsqlParameter(kvp.Key, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)
    {
        Value = kvp.Value
    }));
```

or via the `DbCommand`:

```cs
using (var cmd = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    bool wasOpen = cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
    if (!wasOpen) cmd.Connection.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = ...;
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(kvp.Key, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)
            {
                Value = kvp.Value
            });
        }

        var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!wasOpen) cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```